# What is the brownish region filled with tiny thread like structure on my Apple?

Tags: apples

[image]
I was having my Apple, and just as I was eating it, I saw this, so what is it?

Comment: That’s bitter pit, a disease that can happen. For details see the linked Q/A.

Comment: See also https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/125632/how-to-prevent-these-brown-spots-in-an-apple

Comment: @Stephie The duplicate question explains nicely what this is and how it came to be but it doesn't say anything about whether the apple is still save to eat.

Comment: @quarague see the answer in the second link (comment above, can’t add it as section duplicate target). Safe, but probably unpleasant.

Comment: @Stephie Thanks. Maybe copy your answer from the question in comments to the question linked to as duplicate so we have all the information about this in one place.

Comment: I believe the photo also adds value for future searchers. I wouldn't have assumed this one and the duplicate were the same disease without the commentary.

Comment: On further research I'm not convinced these _are_ the same disease. I'd vote to reopen if I had the rep.